# Firebase Realtime Database Issue when trying to add item to the database in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have been getting an error which says the key must not be empty or contain characters like '$', '[', ']', '#' when I am trying to push my data into the database. It is strange as I don't get this error every time but only once in a while. I can't understand why. Could someone please help me. Thanks.

```
       // Convert C# Dictionary to NSDictionary
            var _item = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(ItemDict.Values.ToArray()
                                               , ItemDict.Keys.ToArray());

            DatabaseReference newItem = root.Database.GetRootReference().GetChild("Posts").GetChildByAutoId();
            newItem.SetValue(_item);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some of the values in your `ItemDict` have keys that include `$`, `[`, `]`, `.` or `#` and those characters are not allowed in keys in the Realtime Database.

You'll want to filter such character from the keys before you pass them to Firebase.